# What does "$(@:H)" do in MakeFile?

Tags: makefile

I was speaking with one of my fellow interns at lunch today who is working almost exclusively in Makefile this summer, and he mentioned that he has no idea what $(@:H) means or does. My google-fu is failing me, as I cannot find it anywhere on the web, and was hoping you guys could help me out.

Comment: That's a make variable with the name `@:H` which isn't a default variable that I'm aware of. So that should, unless defined somewhere, expand to the empty string. Are you sure that's the syntax you/he saw? And not `$(@D)` or `$(@:H=c)` or similar?

Comment: He claims that's what he saw. If it's a non-default variable, I'm assuming it's already defined somewhere else in the program, then. I've never touched Make myself, so I haven't the slightest clue.

Comment: That would be an awkward variable to have chosen to use since it is so close to valid variable uses. Unless, of course, this isn't GNU make and is some other make instead where that means something.

Comment: Ah. Looks like it might be BSD make. The `:H` modifier there "Replaces each word in the variable with everything but the last component."

Comment: I'm not sure what OS he's working in, but that would make sense, since I know some of the machines here run FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is GNU make then that's just the expansion of the (oddly named) `@:H` variable. Which isn't a default variable (and isn't a variable that can be set with the normal assignment syntax) and would be an odd choice for a variable name to begin with as it is very close to real variable expansions.

It is much more likely that this is referring to BSD make where `:H` is a variable modifier which (excerpt from the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make%281%29)):

> :H
>
> Replaces each word in the variable with everything but the last component.